# How to implement MVVMi in Android (Java, not Kotlin)?

Tags: android, android-mvvm, clean-architecture, dagger-hilt

I am trying to implement clean architecture in Android (Java, not Kotlin). Specifically I want to implement the MVVMi pattern, explained in [this post](https://medium.com/@thereallukesimpson/clean-architecture-with-mvvmi-architecture-components-rxjava-8c5093337b43).

Other tools I am using:

- Hilt, for dependency injection.
- Retrofit / RXJava
- Room Database

I have the code put together like this:

### Interactor

```
public class BreviarioInteractor {

    @Inject
    public BreviarioRepository mRepository;

    public Observable<JsonElement> searchBreviario(String query, HashMap<String,String> map) {
        Log.d("BreviarioInteractor","a");
        return new GetBreviarioUseCaseImpl(mRepository).getBreviario(query,map);
    }
}
```

### UseCase

```
public class GetBreviarioUseCaseImpl {
    @Inject
    public BreviarioRepository mRepository;

    public GetBreviarioUseCaseImpl(BreviarioRepository mRepository) {
        this.mRepository = mRepository;
        //mRepository is NULL here
        Log.d("aaa",this.mRepository.toString());

    }

    public Observable<JsonElement> getBreviario(String query, HashMap<String,String> map) {
        return mRepository.getBreviario(query,map);
    }
}
```

### Repository

```
public class BreviarioRepository {
    private static final String TAG = "BreviarioRepository";

    ApiService apiService;

    @Inject
    public BreviarioRepository(ApiService apiService) {
        this.apiService = apiService;
    }


    public Observable<JsonElement> getBreviario(String query, HashMap<String,String> map){
        Log.d("abcd-2","b");
        return apiService.getBreviario(query,map);
    }
}
```

### ViewModel

```
public class BreviarioViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private static final String TAG = "BreviarioViewModel";

    private BreviarioRepository breviarioRepository;
    private BreviarioInteractor breviarioInteractor;

    private final CompositeDisposable disposables = new CompositeDisposable();
    private final MutableLiveData<ApiResponse> mLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();


    @ViewModelInject
    public BreviarioViewModel(BreviarioRepository breviarioRepository) {
        this.breviarioRepository = breviarioRepository;
        breviarioInteractor = new BreviarioInteractor();

    }

    // ...

    public void loadBreviario(String theDate, HashMap<String, String> map) {
        Log.d("abcd1","a");

        disposables.add(breviarioInteractor.searchBreviario(theDate, map)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnSubscribe((d) -> mLiveData.setValue(ApiResponse.loading()))
                .subscribe(
                        result -> mLiveData.setValue(ApiResponse.success(result)),
                        throwable -> mLiveData.setValue(ApiResponse.error(throwable))
                ));
    }


    //...

    @Override
    protected void onCleared() {
        super.onCleared();
        disposables.clear();
    }

}
```

### The problem

My problem here is that the repository is null in the UseCase.

I appreciate any help solving this problem as well as any suggestions to improve my code.

I've been looking for examples that implement MVVMi with no success. Most of the examples are based on Kotlin. I found [this repository](https://github.com/Valgaal/FilmBrowser) in Java code, but it uses Dagger for dependency injection and the repository is implemented differently, it uses Converters, etc.

I'm just getting started with clean architecture as well as RXJava so I'm a bit lost on all of this.

Comment: can you share your Repository Module which will be providing the instance of your repository where ever it is requested using @Inject

Comment: @DinkarKumar i don't have Repository Module, I'm including the Repository in the ViewModel like this: `@ViewModelInject
    public BreviarioViewModel(BreviarioRepository breviarioRepository) {
        this.breviarioRepository = breviarioRepository;
        breviarioInteractor = new BreviarioInteractor();
    }` I don't know if I'm wrong, but that's how I understood from reading the Hilt documentation. I have done tests without Interactor / UseCase and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem: I was not injecting the repository correctly into the interactor.

As the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#define-bindings) explains, the object should be passed to the constructor and annotated with `@Inject`

### Interactor

```
public class BreviarioInteractor {
    private final BreviarioRepository mRepository;

    @Inject
    public BreviarioInteractor(BreviarioRepository mRepository) {
        this.mRepository = mRepository;
    }
```

Then in the ViewModel I have to pass the repository in parameter when I create the Interactor:

### ViewModel

```
@ViewModelInject
public BreviarioViewModel(BreviarioRepository breviarioRepository) {
    this.breviarioRepository = breviarioRepository;
    breviarioInteractor = new BreviarioInteractor(breviarioRepository);
}
```